# Dash plotly update label in between calculation

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm new to dash plotly and using this for some of my personal projects. Now I have a long calculation running and I need to update some status bar like label with progress with the calculation. Something like this

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Button("Start calculation",n_clicks=0,id="btn")
        html.Label('Calculation 1 complete', style={'display':"none"}, id='cal1'),
        html.Label('Calculation 2 complete', style={'display':"none"}, id='cal1'),
        html.Label('Calculation 3 complete', style={'display':"none"}, id='cal1'),
])
])


@app.callback(
    [Output('cal1', 'style'),
    Output('cal2', 'style'),
    Output('cal3', 'style')],
    [Input('btn', 'n_clicks')])
def calculation():
    # long calulation 1
    #> make label id cal1 visible

    # long calulation 2
    #> make label id cal2 visible

    # long calulation 3
    #> make label id cal3 visible

    # calculation complete
```

But I don't know how to achieve this. I can only have callbacks that have specific input that starts the function and at the end of the function update some specific output. Unlike pure javascript I cant just update some html anytime inside the function. Can anyone help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the `html.Label` in an `html.Div` and pass `style={'display':'none'}` inside that div, not in the `html.Label`.

Then to make the label display, remove `style={'display':'none'}` by returning {} after each calculation completes.

Comment: This answer is very incomplete... and does this even work? Can the display properties really be modified outside of the app layout? If so, how?

Comment: Some possibly useful references: https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates , https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store , https://dash.plotly.com/sharing-data-between-callbacks